# How to fix NestJS deployment error to the Vercel?

Tags: node.js, deployment, backend, nestjs, vercel

[image]

this is the now.json

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "name": "nestjs-now",
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "dist/main.js",
      "use": "@now/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "dist/main.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm not sure what's the reason and how to fix.
I just followed the vercel tutorial to deploy my nestjs backend project, but don't works.
It inclues GraphQL APIs and Rest APIs together as well as socket.io server.

Answer (score 9):

### Why it doesn't work?

Serverless Functions on Vercel (at the moment) do not accept a build step for the code of the function. For that reason, any backend framework that needs a "build step" to generate a server, will not work.

### What Vercel is best for?

Frontend deployments and Serverless Functions as helpers. Full-blown APIs should be deployed elsewhere. You can check the following resources:

- https://vercel.com/guides
- https://vercel.com/import
- https://vercel.com/docs/runtimes#official-runtimes

### What are my options?

I recommend that you use Heroku or Digital Ocean as alternatives.

---

### Update 2021-11-11

Now you can deploy **any** framework with SSR, API routes, and Edge Functions (soon) to Vercel. Just make sure you are following the [File System API](https://vercel.com/docs/file-system-api) specification.

You can read the [introduction](https://vercel.com/docs/file-system-api#introduction) section for more information. Remember that Vercel is a platform optimized for frontend deployments.

Comment: is this still true today?

Comment: I will edit. Thanks for flagging

Comment: @Jonathan the link is dead

Comment: I wrote this for Angular, could probably be edited - https://dev.to/jdgamble555/how-to-deploy-angular-universal-to-vercel-31d0

Answer (score 3):

the problem is that VERCEL looks for the DIST folder as soon as it starts the BUILD process

What you can do is remove the DIST folder from the `.gitignore` this way it will resolve the 404

after that, whenever you make a new deploy it is necessary to force deploy without cache to compile your dist againe

Answer (score 3):

In your **production dashboard** you will find this buttom with
[vercel function logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6S3Vn.png)
and inside you can find what is breaking your app

but, in my opinion, the first mistake that are crashing is about your **VERCEL.JSON** file:

When you are building a serveless app in **nestjs**, you will not renderize by *dist/* or *output/*, you gotta render from your **src/**, so your vercel.json must be like this:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "src/main.ts",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "src/main.ts",
            "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE"]
        }
    ]
}
```

And you must do set it [with the documentation help](https://vercel.com/docs/project-configuration)
calling your API like it needs.

This following resolution doesn't works with **NESTJS/SWAGGER** because it is not sending **SwaggerUIBundle** to browser [as in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENQrb.png), but a solution to the same issue can be founded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63363123/swagger-ui-bundle-js-too-large-for-aws-lambda-and-alb) with only swagger in C# (and if is your case, you can try to adapt it to nestjs/swagger)

[I oppened this to find some solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62977018/how-to-fix-nestjs-deployment-error-to-the-vercel?rq=1)

Comment: When I set: "dest": "src/main.ts", for the routes and build, it worked like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully deploy nestjs to vercel and I used the following starter project: https://github.com/nestjs/javascript-starter

1)- first, you need to install `@babel/cli` and `@babel/core` both at the same time, otherwise npx will install out-of-dated babel 6.x. which will cause issues later when building the project using babel, and thats according to babel [own docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli)

2)- remove `@babel/core` from `package.json`

3)- remove `@babel/cli` if exists from `package.json`

4)- remove `package-lock.json`

5)- remove `node_modules`

6)- run the command `npm i`

7)- run the command `npm i --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli`

8)- build/transpile the project using the command `npx babel src --out-dir build`

9)- add `vercel.json` to your project like with following

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "build/main.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "build/main.js",
            "methods": [ "GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

10)- now push this to github, then deploy to vercel