# swagger-ui-bundle.js too large for AWS Lambda and ALB

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

Updated to .NET Core 3.1 and the latest version of Swashbuckle but found the swagger UI wasn't working correctly.  The swagger-ui-bundle.js was failing to load with a 502.  Tracked this down to a AWS ALB error saying the response was too big.  ALB targeting Lambda limits responses to 1MB.  Confirmed the swagger-ui-bundle.js is almost 1MB (technically 995KB).

Is there anyway to reduce the size of swagger-ui-bundle.js or some alternate way to reference it (through CDN maybe)?

I'm using the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.5.1 Nuget package with .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/6146

Comment: @Helen thanks the solution mentioned in the above post helped

Answer (score 2):

This should fix the issue:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
  c.InjectJavascript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/swagger-ui/4.1.3/swagger-ui-bundle.js", "text/javascript");
  c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{_swaggerVersion}/swagger.json", _appSettings.ApiName);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue for me. I did not use the exact cloudflare link provided here, instead I checked my swagger ui version and looked for the link that matched the bundle.js for it. Differences between versions could causes errors so I'd suggest anyone using this solution follow these additional steps.

Answer (score 0):

I was terribly stuck with this issue, which happened over-a-sudden and I couldn't test my API endpoints, somehow the Swagger page doesn't pick up the necessary packages from swagger-ui when it's being loaded on the client-side page.

**Solution**

Manually injecting the scripts and styles, at the `app.UseSwaggerUI()` method, worked for me:

```
string myApiVersion = "v1";
string myAppName = "CareMatchPro";
string swaggerVersion = "4.15.5";

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
....

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseSwagger();
....

string pkgUrl = "https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@";
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
    c.HeadContent = 
        $"<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" " +
        $"href=\"{pkgUrl}{swaggerVersion}/swagger-ui.css\" />";
    c.InjectStylesheet($"{pkgUrl}{swaggerVersion}/swagger-ui.css", "text/css");
    c.InjectJavascript($"{pkgUrl}{swaggerVersion}/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js", "text/javascript");
    c.InjectJavascript($"{pkgUrl}{swaggerVersion}/swagger-ui-bundle.js", "text/javascript");
    c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{myApiVersion}/swagger.json", myAppName);
});
```

I hope this helps anyone avoiding time waste - and making up for the time waste I've done... :)