# .net Core Swagger: SwaggerUIBundle is not defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am using .net core 3.1 and its a lambda. This is an API project which has our api endpoints and uses Swagger. Locally this works fine and I can see swagger ui loaded and I can see my endpoints fine. But when I push this to my server, the swagger ui is not loaded and in the console I see **502 error against swagger-ui-bundle.js**.

Since this is an API project I am not adding this bundle anywhere in my project. May be this is part of the swashbuckle nuget packages.
I have the following packages already added:
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI

Below is the code I have:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
        {
            Title = "Data API",
            Version = "ver1"
        });
    });
}

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
 {
    app.UseMvc();
    app.UseSwagger();

    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>  
    {  
       c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My Test1 Api v1");  
    });
 }
```

Below is the error I get in the console of my api:

```
 index.html:95 Uncaught ReferenceError: SwaggerUIBundle is not defined
    at window.onload (index.html:95:37)
```

Not sure if I am missing something here or I need to check with my team to configure something on our servers to make this work.

Thanks,

Comment: What happens if you add `app.UseStaticFiles();` before the `UseMvc` line?

Comment: Same error. I added above and redeployed. Its throws the same error

Comment: I resolved it using this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63363123/swagger-ui-bundle-js-too-large-for-aws-lambda-and-alb    Solution: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/6146